# webscraping an embedded table with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am learning how to webscrape with rvest and R and I want to extract the table embedded in the below website:

https://perfectunion.us/map-where-are-starbucks-workers-unionizing/

If you scroll midway through you will see an embedded table of starbucks stores and their unionize status.

When I use the CSS selector tool and highlight the table body, I get the code `"td"`.

However when I use the below rvest code, I get:

`{xml_nodeset (0)}`

I have also used the inspection feature to see the table name (below) and I get the same error.

`"table#wpgmza_table_1.responsive.wpgmza_table.dataTable.no-footer.dtr-inline.collapsed"`

Can anyone help me extract that table into R? I am trying to do a science practice project

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse,rvest)

url <- "https://perfectunion.us/map-where-are-starbucks-workers-unionizing/"

sb <- rvest::read_html(url)

#method1:
sb %>% 
  rvest::html_elements("td")

#method2
sb %>% 
rvest::html_elements("table#wpgmza_table_1.responsive.wpgmza_table.dataTable.no-footer.dtr-inline.collapsed")
```

I appreciate any help to ultimately extract that table from the website and bring into R as a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the table is stored as JSON file.  If you use the Network tab from the browser developers tool one can retrieve the link.

url<-"https://perfectunion.us/wp-json/wpgmza/v1/datatables/base64eJy10zFrwzAQBeD-8mYV6rZJQFvo0CWBDIFC4lKu1sUWlRVzkkPA+L9HcVLo1qVa795907sBXdO9OgoBGu+bt-VuWZZrkm+WlQ3R+rosl+ZEvmKzpS-HUAiRJEI-Kjj2dWygHwqFlrpPa5JSpEh1dH3rk7kfYCjSlPbUctpfBSapmonTUXpWOIph+T24RaAHnMj19zvhms-QB3KBx1H92EVG+ymj-ZzRfslozzLa84z24v-tj-vZ1PRb66euG5tGoFDhGvkbUjhYF1nSw21IqE2vM4zjBWiiMh0"

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
```

I'm not sure how stable this link is, it may change on a regular basis.

Comment: thanks! I'm new to webscraping and trying to learn more, is there quick way to validate if I should be using a json package vs. rvest html scraping?

Comment: rvest is a very good package and my first choice but with the dynamic content of today's webpages, rvest will sometimes fail, thus the need to locate the data directly (ie JSON or another API) or resort to rselenium.  Searching here at stack overflow is great resource.  Sorry there are few shortcuts for experience and practice.